# Does the manufacturer reset the metadata shutter count when replacing the shutter?

Tags: metadata, repair, shutter-actuations

I've read about this across different forums but have not found a satisfying answer. Does the manufacturer (Canon in particular) reset the metadata shutter count when replacing a shutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

I've changed the shutter on my Canon 5D Mk3 due of one of blades desync at a shutter count of ~170000 (more than the expected of 150000). Now when I'm looking with the same tool and it says 53371.

Note: I use(d) an utility which I downloaded from http://www.shutteractuations.com/

Now it seems that they offer just the online option.